# How to setup an Intel MKL environment?

Tags: intel, intel-mkl

How to create and source an Intel MKL environment with a specific version of python?

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/distribution-for-python.html                     
                     
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl.html

Answer (score 0):

Using conda you can create environment with specific version of python.

```html
conda config --add channels intel
```

```html
conda create -n idp intelpython3_core python=3.x
```

Please note that "x" in "python=3.x" should signify which version of Python* you would like to install.

Documentation link:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/using-intel-distribution-for-python-with-anaconda.html